# How to define protobuf file out of gRPC Service application and use it as GrpcServices="Server"

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, asp.net5

in my .sln I have gRPCService1, gRPCService2 ... etc , and each of this services contains .proto files into Proto folder, so I just want to create shared folder for those services, and transfer all those service proto files to this shared folder, how to use that proto into my gRPC service application and also into my Client side application ?

Comment: You could make a different repository only with your protos and then import it where ever you want

Comment: @Paplusc so the repository should be some class library and from my grpc service add that class library reference into it ??? can you show me an example ?

Comment: You cite .NET, however there are two ways of doing everything in .NET; the Google way is to define a .proto schema (text file) and generate types from that, but there's also protobuf-net.Grpc which adds code-first (i.e. you define your types in code, and optionally generate a schema from that, if you want) - which approach are you taking? And have you read any of the "getting started in gRPC" docs for .NET (for either approach)

Comment: my question is about directories.
look, in my .sln  I have gRPCService1, gRPCService2 ... etc ,
and each of this services contains .proto files into Proto folder ,
so I just want to create shared folder for those services, and transfer all those service proto files to this shared folder  @MarcGravell